# Deleting rows with a cell checking if its string or int

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data of 500k rows and the formatting of the whole data is kinda inconsistent
I'm using Spyder, pandas to do the cleaning of data

I will have a column that consists of numbers or string.
I would like to delete the entire row if that particular cell is in string

As shown below is my code with some adjustment due to confidential info

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
mydataset = pd.read_csv('test.txt', error_bad_lines=False,
                    engine='python',
                    index_col=False,header = None,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,  
                    sep="[\s|,|/]",names=["1","2","3","4","a","b","c",
                    "h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","f","g",
                    "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                    "5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"])

print (mydataset.shape)

columns =['3','4','h','a','b','c','i','j','k','l','m','n','f','g']
mydataset.drop(columns,inplace=True,axis=1)
print (mydataset.shape)

mydataset = mydataset[(mydataset.q.notnull())&(mydataset.r.notnull())& 
(mydataset.s.notnull())&(mydataset.2.notnull())&(mydataset.2 != "@")]
```

Pardon the naming convention of the header.

```
example of data:
1    2    3    4   <--header
abc  123  123  bcd <--Data
123  123  123  bcd <--Data
```

would like to detect the "abc" and remove the whole row

Please advice!

Comment: check out the linked answer.

Answer (score -1):

using dataframe.map, it may like below(i am not quiet sure that all grammer is right):

```
def remove(row):
     if 'abc' in row:
          row = []
mydataset.map(remove)
```

Comment: hello!
The string can be a lot of different combination of letter though so by doing if 'abc' is kinda hardcoding it